# python linux search a word start with a word

Tags: python, linux, find

**I want to have a method that return true when a string contain a certain word example i want the word musique and i want to check it with "musique.txt"  i want to return true because "musique.txt"* contain the word musique*

```
def contains_word(contain, word):
    print((' ' + word + ' ') in (' ' + contain + ' '))
    return (' ' + word + ' ') in (' ' + contain + ' ')


contains_word('musique.txt', 'musique')  # True
contains_word('musique1.txt', 'musique')  # False
```

Comment: my code doesn't works because it said false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
def contains_word(contain, word):
  with open(contain,'r') as f:
    text = f.readlines()

  for i in text:
    temp = i.split()
    for j in temp:
      if word == j:
        return True

  return False

contains_word('musique.txt', 'musique')
```

Basically in this code, each and every word is matched against the provided word.

Comment: DOESN'T WORKS :( :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    class Dossier:
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py", line 110, in Dossier
    contains_word('musique.txt', 'musique')
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py", line 99, in contains_word
    with open(contain, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'musique.txt'

Comment: @Songfordenise You should have a file with name 'musique.txt' to run or any other file which you can pass to the function.

Comment: where i can write my path to my folder ? cause i have musique.txt in my folder

Comment: __contains_word('path/to/file', 'musique')__

Comment: @Songfordenise If it solves your problem, you can accept it as answer and upvote it. Glad to help you.